# Working with CLang in c++

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

I have a compilation error in my program related to the included files, in my program I am including this files:

```
#include "clang/AST/ASTConsumer.h"
#include "clang/AST/RecursiveASTVisitor.h"
#include "clang/Frontend/CompilerInstance.h"
#include "clang/Frontend/FrontendAction.h"
#include "clang/Tooling/Tooling.h"
```

The error message I get when I compile the program using g++ is:

```
In file included from /usr/include/clang/AST/APValue.h:17:0,
                 from /usr/include/clang/AST/Decl.h:17,
                 from /usr/include/clang/AST/RecursiveASTVisitor.h:17,
                 from FindClassDecls.cpp:2:
/usr/include/clang/Basic/LLVM.h:20:34: fatal error: llvm/Support/Casting.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

I don't have any idea how to solve the problem, and also I am not sure that I installed the CLang library correctly, so can you please tell me how to solve the problem or how to install it correctly on linux (Ubuntu).

Comment: Clang is not a library.

Comment: @Jefffrey I beg to differ http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX.html

Comment: @SirDarius, that's the API to interface with Clang. :/

Comment: @Jefffrey I guess that is what the OP is trying to do, interface with clang.

Comment: @SirDarius, that doesn't change the fact that [Clang is a front-end compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clang), not a library.

Comment: @Jefffrey yes clang is a driver program to a set of libraries, and a front-end compiler. However, the OP stated that he installed the "Clang library" in Ubuntu, which conveniently exists as a set of packages named `libclang1`, `libclang-dev`, `libclang-common-dev`. Therefore there is such a thing called the "Clang library", and this is what the OP is talking about. I hope you can agree and we can delete all of these comments :)

Comment: @Jefffrey: you're not correct. Clang is a set of modular libraries for implementing a front-end of a C-like compiler. It also comes with a gcc-compatible driver that emits LLVM IR from C, C++ and Objective C. It is correct, therefore, to refer to a "clang library". Moreover, the OP's code very clearly suggests this is precisely the use case in question.

Comment: Here is my project: https://github.com/hun-nemethpeter/cpp-reflector-mini

Answer (score 6):

It seems that you have the Clang headers installed, but not the LLVM headers (which Clang relies upon). When you are compiling your code, you need to pass the path of LLVM headers with `-I` to your compiler, as usual.

I'd grab a pre-built Clang+LLVM from [the Download page](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html) and compile/link against that.

Answer (score 2):

sudo apt-get install libclang-3.8-dev # or libclang-3.9-dev